# Almost sure convergence to 0 implies probability convergence to 0

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

I've seen proof of almost sure convergence implying probability convergence but I want to ask whether or not the "proof" for the 0 case is correct:
$X_n$ converges almost surely to $X$ if $\mathbb{P}(\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n = X) = 1$.

Given that $\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n = 0$ then $X_n$ converges to $X = 0$ almost surely, then I prove that it converges in probability to 0 by considering for $\epsilon > 0$,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(|X_n - 0| > \epsilon) \\ = \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(|X_n| > \epsilon)\\ = \mathbb{P}(\lim_{n\to\infty} |X_n| > \epsilon)\\
= \mathbb{P}(0 > \epsilon) \\ = 0
$$

since $\epsilon > 0$. So since I've shown the probability goes to zero, it converges in probability. Is this how it's done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second equality is wrong. You cannot take the limit inside the probability.

$P(|X_n| >\epsilon)\leq P(\cup_{m \geq n} (|X_m| >\epsilon)$ so $\lim P(|X_n| >\epsilon) \leq P(\lim \sup (|X_n| >\epsilon) =0$ since $\lim \sup P(|X_n| >\epsilon)$ has probability $0$ by assumption.

Comment: Thanks. Just to make sure, you used $\lim \sup P(|X_n| > \epsilon) = P(\lim \sup |X_n| > \epsilon)$?

Comment: No, you have $\leq$ but not equality in general.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to salvage your proof. Note that $P(|X_n|>\epsilon) = E(1_{|X_n|>\epsilon})$. Since $X_n \to 0$ a.s,  we have $1_{|X_n|>\epsilon} \to 0$ a.s.

Since $1_{|X_n|>\epsilon}\leq 1$, the dominated convergence theorem applies and yields $\lim_n E(1_{|X_n|>\epsilon}) = E(0) = 0$.

Comment: For the first line, how does it imply $1_{|X_n| > \epsilon} \to 0$ almost surely? I get the intuition that $X_n$ goes to $0$, so the indicator of the event that $\epsilon < 0$ evaluates to $0$, but is there a theorem or something?

Comment: @OneGapLater Consider $w$ such that $X_n(w) \to 0$. Then there exists some $N(w)$ such that $$n\geq N(w)\implies |X_n(w)|\leq \epsilon \implies  1_{|X_n(w)|>\epsilon} = 0$$
So $1_{|X_n(w)|>\epsilon}$ converges to $0$ as a sequence in $n$. And this holds for almost all $w$.